# What is delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am a beginner of C#, and I can't understand `delegate`.
Can anybody provide me some better links through which I can understand quickly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474439/please-explain-net-delegates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining delegates with adequate details id beyond the scope of this answer. I'd point you to few articles that can help you understand this.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(VS.71).aspx

From MSDN..

> A delegate in C# is similar to a
>   function pointer in C or C++. Using a
>   delegate allows the programmer to
>   encapsulate a reference to a method
>   inside a delegate object. The delegate
>   object can then be passed to code
>   which can call the referenced method,
>   without having to know at compile time
>   which method will be invoked. Unlike
>   function pointers in C or C++,
>   delegates are object-oriented,
>   type-safe, and secure.

A delegate declaration defines a type that encapsulates a method with a particular set of arguments and return type. For static methods, a delegate object encapsulates the method to be called. For instance methods, a delegate object encapsulates both an instance and a method on the instance. If you have a delegate object and an appropriate set of arguments, you can invoke the delegate with the arguments.

> An interesting and useful property of
>   a delegate is that it does not know or
>   care about the class of the object
>   that it references. Any object will
>   do; all that matters is that the
>   method's argument types and return
>   type match the delegate's. This makes
>   delegates perfectly suited for
>   "anonymous" invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the MSDN:

[delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(VS.71).aspx):

> A delegate declaration defines a reference type that can be used to encapsulate a method with a specific signature. A delegate instance encapsulates a static or an instance method. Delegates are roughly similar to function pointers in C++; however, delegates are type-safe and secure.

[An Introduction to Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301810.aspx), the first sentence of which states:

> Callback functions are certainly one of the most useful programming mechanisms ever created.

So, if you are familiar with callbacks, you have some understanding of delegates already.